# custom UITableViewCell with label and UISlider worked fine in 6 crashes in ios 7. ?? UITableViewCellScrollView?

Tags: uitableview, ios7, uislider

I was going to post this as a Question but I worked it out and thought I'd share it in case anyone else ran into this.

I have a custom tableViewCell called SliderCell. I use a number of SliderCells on my table.

The SliderCell contains a UISlider and a UILabel.

When the user moves the slider the label is updated with a new value

This is in this method

```
- (IBAction)possibilityDidChange:(UISlider *)sender {
```

Now the sender in this case is the UISlider control

To set the value of UILabel I needed to get the tableviewCell (sliderCell) that the sender sits on.'

Originally i got this as follows

```
SliderCell *theAnimalCell =(SliderCell*)sender.superview.superview;
```

I could then set the label like this

```
theAnimalCell.sliderLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"turtles %@",possibilityString];
```

All well and good when i was using Xcode 4.x and targeting iOS6.1

Now , after deciding that 200m+ cant be wrong I'm just targeting iOS 7 and suddenly I'm getting a crash as sooon as I touch any of my UISliders

I get this error

[UITableViewCellScrollView currentSlider]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

I couldn't find any reference to this class in the documentation.

Comment: Same exact problem here!!

Comment: Are you using a custom slider with your own animations? I am and the animations are no longer working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inspecting the class i discovered what i was expecting to be a SLiderCell was in fact now a UITableViewCellScrollView. 
However if you go up another level by adding an extra .superview you do get to the custom UITableViewCell and it now works again

So the change was from

```
SliderCell *theAnimalCell =(SliderCell*)sender.superview.superview;
```

To this

```
SliderCell *theAnimalCell =(SliderCell*)sender.superview.superview.superview;
```

I guess if you wanted to support both iOS 7 and iOS 6 you would need to check before you tried to grab the custom cell.

Well, thats it , hope this proves useful to someone out there.

Simon

Answer (score 2):

Make a condition like this.

```
AddTOcartCell *cell = ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7) ? (AddTOcartCell*)textField.superview.superview.superview : (AddTOcartCell*)textField.superview.superview;
cell.btnUpdate.hidden=FALSE;
NSLog(@"Call Y%f",cell.frame.origin.y);
[tblProduct setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,cell.frame.origin.y) animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes the reason in **ios 7** is that it returns `UITableViewCellContentView` from this:-

```
settingCustomCell *theAnimalCell =(settingCustomCell*)[[sender superview]superview];
```

So to get `UITableViewCell` in **ios 7** just change your code to this:-

```
settingCustomCell *theAnimalCell =(settingCustomCell*)[[sender superview]superview]superview];
```

***Note :-*** But to ignore any conflict put these both conditions according to ios conditions.